# Solr Processing only Half data

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a solr Index which is fetching data from DIH. When i run the index it is fetching aroung 273453 data but it is processing only 103345.

Why the solr is processing only half data. Kindly Help.

Comment: We don't have nearly enough information to help you.  Please edit your question and include more details.  Where is the DIH fetching from?  What database?  How do you know your query from that database is working?  What shows up in your Solr log file?  What data does get processed?  Which doesn't?  etc etc etc.  You need to tell us **much** more about your problem if you're to have any hope of us helping.

Comment: Please also check also your logs

Comment: Thanks. I checked the log and solved the issue